# get ids for a given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 id   start_date    end_date          
 1    2012-02-05   2012-03-10      
 2    2012-03-05   2012-03-25       
 3    2012-03-19   2012-03-27      
 4    2012-04-01   2012-04-20

Table Name: bulbs
```

Here this table contains information about bulbs which are lights during the given date period. If I select two dates I want to get currently lighting bulb ids for those date range. e.g. for the dates '2012-02-10' and '2012-03-20' this should return ids - 1,2 and 3. I have no idea how to do it. please help.

Comment: Do you mean `'2012-02-10'` to `'2012-03-20'`? 10th to 20th of Feb should only give id 1 from my understanding?  And are your end-dates includive or exclusive?  *(If querying `'2012-03-10'` to `'2012-03-20'`, should it return id 1 along with id's 2 and 3?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont get how 2012-02-10 and 2012-02-20 would give you ids 1,2,3, if i understand this right it should give just id 1
in that case SQL should be

```
select id from bulbs where
end_date >= '2012-02-10' and
start_date <= '2012-02-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id 
from bulbs
where '2012-02-10' <= start_date
and ('2012-02-20' between start_date and end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  bulbs
WHERE
  start_date <= '2012-02-20'
  AND end_date >= '2012-02-10'
```

This type of query, however, is extremely slow over large volumes of data.

This is because an index on (start_date, end_date) doesn't help any more than an index on just (start_date).

One way to improve performance to to give both an upper and lower limit on the start date.  This can be done if you know the maximum number of days between start_date and end_date.

If, for example, they are never more than 60 days appart, you can do this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  bulbs
WHERE
      start_date <= '2012-02-20'
  AND start_date >= '2012-02-10' - 60
  AND end_date   >= '2012-02-10'
```

Comment: This is even better. Thanks a lot.